# How to display pdf in a WebView in terms of UI and UX - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, user-interface, webview, user-experience

Brief about the app: The app parses html documents and load it in the app as a web view.

In the iOS app I like to show PDF files. There is a structure XML that would contain the whole structure.

**Case 1:** For a simple PDF file it would look like the following in the structure.xml

```
<node id="Nc13d37aa" node_id="82cd790d-e5f0-4ee6-a26c-a6e400af8541" type="publication" default="TEST_Pub" secured="false">
                <language name="en-GB" path="X-BIKE-401/en-GB/publications/TEST_Pub-003.00.pdf">
                  <title>(Test-)Publication</title>
                </language>
              </node>
```

**Case 2:** In a more complex scenario one publication might contain a so called ATI's(Additional technical information) This would look like this:

```
<node id="Nd747c4dc" node_id="b4528fb8-c615-4b96-945d-a5af009325f2" type="publication" default="TEST_Pub_ATI" secured="false">
                <language name="en-GB" path="X-BIKE-401/en-GB/publications/TEST_Pub_ATI-003.00.pdf">
                  <title>(Test-)Publication with ATI</title>
                  <atis>
                    <ati id="ati584a41ee" internal_id="af720ef4-5238-4fb4-ba8b-a5ae00debfae" code="Test_ATI" type="Service Letter" required="false" issuecode="Test_ATI_03" issuenumber="3" revisionnumber="0" href="X-BIKE-401\en-GB\ati\Test_ATI-003.00.pdf">(Test-)ATI</ati>
                  </atis>
                </language>
              </node>
```

The idea here is, that we have additional legacy documents accompanying a legacy publication. The idea here would be, that we show the normal legacy publication, but have an additional area in the view, that indicates the user, that there ARE ATIs, and a way for him to view the ATIs - but also get back to the original publication. An ATI is usually some information

**Case 3:** There is also the case, that one or many ATIs are mandatory. 
This means, that the user needs to read & confirm those first, before he can read the actual publication. This will be like:

```
<node id="N5a3c00f" node_id="09fe8d7b-a95d-4da8-bf06-a5af00933ddc" type="publication" default="TEST_Pub_mATI" secured="false">
                <language name="en-GB" path="X-BIKE-401/en-GB/publications/TEST_Pub_mATI-003.00.pdf">
                  <title>(Test-)Publication with MANDATORY ATI</title>
                  <atis>
                    <ati id="ati35c8ee0e" internal_id="60dfaa70-f017-44ea-9190-a5ae00df2494" code="Test_ATI_MAND1" type="Service Bulletin" required="true" issuecode="Test_mATI_03" issuenumber="3" revisionnumber="0" href="X-BIKE-401\en-GB\ati\Test_ATI_MAND1-003.00.pdf">(Test-)ATI1 (MANDATORY)</ati>
                    <ati id="atic771b1b6" internal_id="d1cffa4b-b1be-4bbb-8dc0-a743010cf246" code="Test_ATI_MAND2" type="Service Bulletin" required="true" issuecode="Test_mATI2_01" issuenumber="1" revisionnumber="0" href="X-BIKE-401\en-GB\ati\Test_ATI_MAND2-001.00.pdf">(Test-)ATI2 (MANDATORY)</ati>
                  </atis>
                </language>
              </node>
```

You can see, that two have the @required set to "true". 
In this case we need to first show the first ATI, request the user to "confirm" somewhere that he read it. move on to the next required ATI and conform this as well. and once he has confirmed all the ATIs, he can view the publication itself. 
Still he needs to be able to reopen the ATIs (similar to the previous point) and look them up again - without confirmation again. 
The user needs to reconfirm, once the publication is closed.

**Question:** **For case 2 & 3, how would this might look like? a mockup of it how would it be?** Ideally a proposed solution best in terms of UI and UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you this way , it may solve your question :

**CASE 1 :**

Simply Take a UIWebView and show PDF url link , then WebView will render it perfectly .

**CASE 2 :**

In case 2 you are first showing the case 1 where you show simple PDF and showing it by rendering the web view but then this PDF has extra information called ATI that we need to show this somehow on the web view. So for example a button that when you click on it it will show the extra information maybe in a pop up and then there should be a navigation back to the original PDF

**CASE 3:**

Use some Image Flipper library to show multiple pdf doc in which you can show some sort of info to acknowledge the user about there are more than one doc is there for navigation .

For Flipper follow this library : https://cocoapods.org/pods/DJKFlipper

**Thanks.**